# Cross origin error between angular cli and flask

Tags: python-3.x, angular, typescript, flask, angular-ui-router

first i post the user id and password from the **UI**(angular) to flask

```
  public send_login(user){
           console.log(user)
           return 
     this.http.post(this.apiURL+'/login',JSON.stringify(user),this.httpOptions)
    .pipe(retry(1),catchError(this. 
     handleError))
     }
```

next i received it from backend

[backend error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fXT7.png)

all the operations are working properly but at console the cross origin error is raising

[Error at UI console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isYQW.png)

the http option in Ui side is mentioned below

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  // Http Options
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:9000',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT",
      'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
      'MyClientCert': '',        // This is empty
      'MyToken': '' 
    })
  }
```

the cors declared at backend is metioned below

```
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/login": {"origins": "*"}})
 @app.route('/login', methods=['GET','POST'])
 def loginForm():
 json_data = ast.literal_eval(request.data.decode('utf-8'))
  print('\n\n\n',json_data,'\n\n\n')
```

im not able to find were is the problem is raising

> Note: cross origin arising in the time of login process other wise in the consecutive steps

Comment: can you add the `OPTIONS`  in `@app.route('/login', methods=['GET','POST'])` ?

Comment: which port is angular running, which one is flash running. Did you set up a proxy config? There is a description of how to setup a proxy here: https://angular.io/guide/build

Answer (score 0):

add below code in your app.py

```
CORS(app, supports_credentials=True)
```

and from frontend use

```
{with-credentials :true}
```

it will enable the communication between the frontend and backend

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems the call is not leaving the front end (at least in my experience it is like this), because the browsers are securing this.

Create a new file `proxy.conf.json` in `src/` folder of your project.

```
{
  "/backendApiUrl": {      <--- This needs to reflect the server backend base path
    "target": "http://localhost:9000",    <-- this is the backend server name and port
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"    <--- optional, this will give some debug output
  }
}
```

In the file `angular.json` (CLI configuration file), add the following `proxyConfig` option to the serve target:

```
"projectname": {
  "serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
      "browserTarget": "your-application-name:build",
      "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"      <--- this is the important addition
    },
```

Simply call `ng serve` to run the dev server using this proxy configuration.

You can read the section `Proxying to a backend server` in https://angular.io/guide/build

Hope this helps.