# Cors error when trying to consume Asp.net core web api from angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a AspNetCore WebApi that is consumed by an Angular (8) Client.
I get this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://webapi.domain.xyz' from origin 'http://client.domain2.xyz' has
been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

The request from angular is send via

```
getAll(): Observable<any[]> {
return this.http.get<any[]>(this.url, {headers: this.authService.getHttpOptions()});
}

getHttpOptions():any {

const headers = new HttpHeaders({
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
'Content-Type':  'application/json',
'Authorization': this.authorizationHeaderValue // Token!
})
return headers;
```

WebApi startup.cs has

```
     services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("Allow",
               builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyOrigin();

                });
        });
```

in the ConfigureService method and

```
app.UseCors("Allow");
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseMvc();
```

in the Configure method.

Why my CORS policy isn't used?

Comment: Do you use angular proxy?

Comment: The message you describe at the top, is it shown in the browser?

Comment: I wrote an answer how to configure angular proxy here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60318355/cross-origin-error-between-angular-cli-and-flask/60319789#60319789

Comment: I get the error in the console of the developers tools in Chrome.

Comment: I guess your backend was never contacted by the front end because Chrome prohibited it. If you use angular proxy both frontend and backend will go to the same protocol, host and port and chrome will allow passing of it

Comment: Which port do you use to access angular, which one to access asp.net? I assume the angular is accessed using ng serve which default port is 4200 and the asp.net with the port 80 so Chrome blocks this cross origin request.

Comment: angular client and api are on an IIS Server with own URIs both defined with port 80.
So, since I dont use ng serve I doubt your approach with the proxy will help but I'll try.

Comment: for development of the angular application `ng serve` is quite handy with using proxy. In the final application will both be served from different hosts?

Comment: In development it worked fine with localhost and different ports (since Cors doesnt kick in) Problem appeared after deploying on the production servers. It seems to be a problem on the webapi-side since I get the same problem when using postman as client (to check the endpoints).

Comment: Sorry, can't help here. Can you update the question so somebody has this information and doesn't need to browse the comments here?

Comment: `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: ...` You can try to install [CORS extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference#cors-preflight-request) in IIS server, and check if it can respond to the preflight request correctly.